# Jquery - Show current div when click a link and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on Show/hide link it shows both divs and I want it to show only its related div. How can I do that? I don't want to use ID's for each div.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/pzc8vy9b/)

```
<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>

    <div class="slidingDiv">
    First div.
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>

    <div class="slidingDiv">
    Second div.
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into the click function, change your code to this:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideUp();    
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzc8vy9b/6/

Answer (score 1):

Use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) by changing

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.slidingDiv {
height:300px;
background-color: #99CCFF;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
    
    <div class="slidingDiv">
    First div.
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
    
    <div class="slidingDiv">
    Second div.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

https://jsfiddle.net/pzc8vy9b/4/

```
<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>

    <div class="slidingDiv">
    First div.
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="main-box">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>

    <div class="slidingDiv">
    Second div.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

---

```
.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```